# I can't get the object in my array list

Tags: java

In my code, I have a super class called `Game` and its sub class `Tower`. `Tower` also has its sub class called `Catapult`. 
The Catapult subclass looks like this:

```
public class Catapult extends Tower {
    public Catapult(){
        super(5,3);
    }
}
```

It calls `Tower` constructor with constant integer values 5 and 3. Then, its superclass `Tower` looks like this:

```
public class Tower extends Game {
    private int damage;
    private int timeStep;
    private int position;
    private boolean willFire;

   public Tower(int damage, int timeStep){
       super.addTower(damage,timeStep);
   }
   public Tower(int damage, int timeStep, int position,boolean willFire){
       this.damage = damage;
       this.timeStep = timeStep;
       this.position = position;
       this.willFire = willFire;
   }
   public void getDamage(){
       super.printDamage();
   }

}
```

So now, having values for the damage and timeStep (5 and 3), `Tower` calls its super constructor (Game):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Game {
    private ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
    private ArrayList<Tower> towers = new ArrayList<Tower>();
    private int corridorLength;
    private int currentPosition = 0;

    public Game(){}

    public Game(int corridorLength){
        this.corridorLength = corridorLength;
    }

    public void addTower(int damage,int timeStep){
       this.towers.add(new Tower(damage,timeStep,this.currentPosition,true));
    // Add tower with current position corrdor length
        System.out.println("Tower added in addTower!");}

    public void printDamage(){
        System.out.println(this.towers.get(this.currentPosition)); // How to get the damage item?
    }
 }
```

So the object `Tower` with its values is being stored in the Array tower (at least I assume so). So, having a non empty array called towers with at least size 1, I am facing some problems here.
First: When I call `Tower.getDamage()` method, it eventually calls the method in the `Game` class which just prints the object `Tower` at index 0. But when I try to do it other way round, like printing the object inside the `Game` class like this(calling straight from the `Game` class, instead of calling through its `Tower` subclass):

```
public void getDamage(){
    System.out.println(this.towers.get(this.currentPosition));
}
```

It throws an out of range Array exception, which I don't get, as the array towers should have an object stored at index 0.

Second: How can I get the actual integer inside the object (Tower) at index 0? So, I can't do like this:

```
this.towers.get(0).damage
```

Comment: On quick glance at your code, I see that you appear to be misusing inheritance in a big way. Why should Tower extend Game? Makes no sense, because how can Tower be a more specialized sub-type of Game?

Comment: Tower is an object in the game. When I say object, I mean like simple object (Car and motorcycle are both objects of Vehicle).

Comment: Also Tower  will not be added to the towers field on contruction. In fact every `new Tower()` will create a new `Game` with an empty towers list.

Comment: Yes, Tower is an object ***in*** the Game, meaning that there is a "has-a" relationship here, Game has Towers, not an "is-a" relationship. Tower isn't a Game.

Comment: Is that a reason, why I am getting so confused with this relationship?

Comment: What is `newTower`? Is it supposed to say `new Tower`? If so I'm completely confused, because the Tower constructor appears to indirectly call the Tower constructor again.

Comment: @cppbeginner Fixed now. My bad

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov Do you see my point about the Tower constructor? The Tower constructor calls super.addTower. This method calls new Tower again, so I think you'll get a StackOverflowError, although I haven't tried running it. Hovercraft Full Of Eels is right that this needs remodelling.

Comment: Inheritance is commonly referred to an "**is a**" relationship. Ask yourself one simple question: Is a Tower a Game? If the answer is "yes" then inheritance **might** be appropriate. If the answer is "no", then inheritance is definitely **not** appropriate.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Game "has-a" Tower. Tower is not a Game

Comment: Ah, my bad this time. I've just seen that it's a different Tower constructor.

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov This means that you should have `class Tower {`, not `class Tower extends Game {`.

Answer (score 1):

Your main question appears to be that you want to use the `Tower` objects from the `Game` class. One issue is that you are incorrectly using inheritance, which I will address later. Another more important issue concerns creating objects. You correctly create an `ArrayList` object with

```
private ArrayList<Tower> towers = new ArrayList<Tower>();
```

However, you never create any `Tower` objects. One way to ensure that you have some `Tower` objects is to create them in the constructor and add them to the list:

```
public Game(int corridorLength){
    this.corridorLength = corridorLength;

    this.towers.add(new Tower());
}
```

If you want to add more than one tower, you probably should do so with a for loop. I leave the details as an exercise to the reader.

Now you have a tower object in your list (or more than one), but the `damage` field is private. In order to access it, you should add a "getter" method to your `Tower` class:

```
public int getDamage() {
    return damage;
}
```

Now you can get a tower from the list:

```
Tower t = towers.get(0);
```

and get its damage value:

```
int damage = t.getDamage();
```

---

**Note about inheritance**

It appears to me that you are confused about how to use inheritance. Inheritance is commonly called an "is a" relationship. Ask yourself one simple question: Is a Tower a Game? If the answer is "yes" then inheritance *might* be appropriate. If the answer is "no", then inheritance is definitely not appropriate.

In this case, it seems to me that a Tower is **not** a Game. On the other hand, a Game **has a** Tower. This suggests that the `Game` class should contain a `Tower` member variable (or field):

```
public class Game {
    private Tower tower;
}
```

Similarly, a Tower **has a** Catapult, so the `Tower` class should contain a `Catapult` member field. Since neither a `Tower` nor a `Catapult` is a `Game`, these classes should **not** extend `Game`. Remove the `extends Game` clauses from both classes.

Comment: The Game already has a member called towers. If you can see, the ArrayList will contain several Tower objects. So 1 Game will have several Towers. Also, for the Catapult, I think it is more of a "is-a" relationship, as Tower will have different types

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the OP questions, it tries to resolve other unrelated issues. For what we now Game and Tower can be `A` and `B`.

Comment: @NiVeR I have edited my answer to address the core question from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the tower's damage, you have to call `.damage` at the end, otherwise the program wants to print the tower instead of the damage.

```
System.out.println(this.towers.get(this.currentPosition).damage);
```

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought, but my IDE says it is an error

Comment: Yeah, because `damage` is a **private** value. Either you make it accessible (`public` in this case) or you provide a getter-method for access (preferable).

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the fields directly because they are private. You should provide getters for each field you'd like to access.

Comment: Yes, thanks. What about the first question? That bothers me so much.

Comment: Are you sure that you added any tower before calling the method to print the first one?

Comment: Yes, I have initialized the first object game as an instance of Game, then I have initialized a new Catapult instance, which I believe it will initialize Tower, based on my code. Then I tried to print "game.getDamage();", which returned me an error. The text "Tower added in addTower!" was given